# Existe alguma opção para indentar o código?

Tags: novo-recurso

Estava editando uma pergunta que achei o código muito bagunçado e cheguei a essa questão. Existe algum modo de indentar o código dentro do stack?

Comment: Seria mesmo muito bom ter algo assim dentro do stack. Normalmente quando eu encontro código mal indentado, eu uso [essa ferramenta](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/10au/indent.html) pra me ajudar a indentar.

Comment: Eu uso o Eclipse para auto identar para mim, mas concordo que seria excelente podermos fazer isso sem precisar copiar e colar em outro lugar, facilitaria muito.

Comment: Que tal ainda uma flag automática para código sem nenhuma indentação? :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A indentação de código atual pode ser usada da seguinte forma. Suponha o seguinte código abaixo em C#:

```
public class Classe
{
public void Funcao() 
{
// Faça alguma coisa
}
}
```

Experimente editar esta resposta, selecione esse trecho acima e aperte <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> (ou clique no ícone de duas-chaves ali em cima do painel). Vocês irão notar que o código recua na indentação. Repetindo o atalho/clique do ícone, ele novamente reindenta.

Agora, experimente no mesmo código recuar a indentação primeiro, depois selecionar apenas isto e reaplicar o atalho:

```
public void Funcao() 
{
// Faça alguma coisa
}
```

O que teremos é isto, mas sem o nível mínimo de indentação pro Markdown reconhecer que é um código:

```
public class Classe
{

    public void Funcao() 
    {
    // Faça alguma coisa
    }

}
```

O editor cria duas quebras de linha, uma em cima e uma embaixo, e indenta o código corretamente. Basta selecionar o texto todo novamente que teremos exatamente o bloco correto:

```
public class Classe
{

    public void Funcao() 
    {
    // Faça alguma coisa
    }

}
```

Não é o ideal, mas é o que eu uso aqui.

Comment: Uso assim também. Ás vezes abro um jsFiddle quando o código é muito e cop-paste. Pelo menso em JavaScript functiona bem.