# Código aparece cortado na minha resposta

Tags: suporte, formatação

Postei uma resposta para [Como tranformar uma expressão matemática em liguagem C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/83228/como-tranformar-uma-express%C3%A3o-matem%C3%A1tica-em-liguagem-c/90605#90605) só que a resposta aparece "cortada".

Editem lá e vejam que, de fato, uma parte do código da função não está aparecendo.

Comment: Julgo que é um problema de formatação. veja [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) as opções de formatação de texto e código.

Answer (score 5):

Editei. Tinhas usado `<pre></pre>`, mas o que era preciso é [indentar o código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3790/129). E isso podes fazer com `CTR + K` ou com o botão de código no editor de texto.

Se juntares texto a explicar o código vais aumentar a probabilidade de receber votos positivos e a resposta fica mais útil a quem quiser compreender o problema e a resposta.

Mais info sobre como formatar texto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 4):

O formato de edição no Stack Overflow é o [Markdown](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown), o GitHub também usa esse formato mas não é exatamente o mesmo daqui. Confira o manual conforme indicado pelo ramaral e Sergio.

O [suporte a tags HTML](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) é limitado e não se recomenda usar, se o Markdown oferecer uma alternativa.

Se a pergunta já tem a tag de linguagem, C no caso, não é necessário colocar a meta tag em HTML (isto é só quando precisamos forçar o *syntax-highlight*):

```
<!-- language: lang-c -->
```

<sub>Uma boa ferramenta para praticar/escrever em Markdown é o [StackEdit.io](https://stackedit.io/editor#).

<sup>(documentos armazenados em [localstorage](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/localstorage), ou seja, não tem "nuvem" envolvida)</sup></sub>